# Exercise question on transitivity on embedding one space into another.

Tags: general-topology

For the following question:

> Let $(X,T)$, $(Y,U)$, and $(Z,V)$ be topological spaces such that there is an embedding of $X$ in $Y$ and an embedding of $Y$ in $Z$.   Prove that there is an embedding of $X$ in $Z$.

I would like to know if my approach is correct. Forgive me if I am insisting on being pedantic in writing out all the details.  I am hoping if I got the details correct.

Since $X$ is an embedding in $Y$, then for every open subset $P$ of $X$ and some open $Q\in U$, $Q\subset Y$, (can I shorten this to "an open $Q\in (Y,U)$" instead?), there exists a homeomorphic mapping $f:X\rightarrow f(P)$ where $f(P)=f(X)\cap Q$.
 
Similarly, $Y$ is an embedding in $Z$, for every open subset $W$ of $Y$ and some open $M\in V$, $M\subset Z$. there exists a homeomorphic mapping $g:Y\rightarrow g(W)$ where $g(W)=g(Y)\cap M.$  So in particular, we can let the open subset $W=f(P)$, then $g\circ f:X\rightarrow g(f(P))\subset g(f(X)),$ where $g(W)=g(f(P))=g(f(X)\cap Q))=g(f(X))\cap g(Q)=g(Y)\cap M.$  Hence we have $X$ is an embedding in $Z$.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As X embeds into Y, there is a homeomorphism f:X -> f(X).
As Y embeds into Z, there is a homeomorphism g:Y -> g(Z).
Show that h, the restriction of g to f(X),
is a homeomorphism h:f(X) -> h(f(X)).
Conclude h$\circ$f:X -> h(f(X)) is a homeomorphism,
that X embeds into Z.

Comment: does my solution follow your outline hint?

Comment: @SethMai I didn't follow it.